# mysql query in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, sql-like

I have the following problem, I have my consult in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM  noticias.historicos WHERE fecha LIKE '%2017-06-23%' AND ( titulo LIKE '%Chile%' OR bajadaNoticia LIKE '%Chile%')
```

its ok, I need transfer this query to mysql codeigniter query, thanks and have nice day

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#regular-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db
              ->select('*')
              ->from('noticias.historicos')
              ->like('fetcha','2017-06-23')
              ->group_start()
              ->like('titulo', 'Chile')
              ->or_like('bajadaNoticia', 'Chile')
              ->group_end()
              ->get();
return $query->result(); //or return $query->result_array();
```

try the above code or refer to this [link here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below mentioned query.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('fecha', '2017-06-23'); 
$this->db->or_like(array('titulo' => 'Chile', 'bajadaNoticia' => 'Chile'));
$query = $this->db->get('historicos'');
```

This will help you.